# KMS.UnrecognizedClientException while accessing ksm encrypted s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-kms

I have an S3 bucket which has static self hosting enabled. I also have a cloud front distribution that points to that bucket. When i try to access the web pages, via cloud front, i get the below error in browser.

[image]

What is the reason for this error? Can anyone help in suggesting a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error for KMS encrypted video content. I was serving the encrypted videos via Cloudfront with Origin Access identity option enabled (OAI). After exploring many options, I came accross this blog [Amazon CloudFront introduces Origin Access Control (OAC)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-cloudfront-introduces-origin-access-control-oac/), which asks to switch to Origin access control (OAC). Just after following the blog step by step the problem was resolved and I was able to play encrypted content. Read the blog thoroughly, they have explained why we have to choose OAC over OAI in such scenarios.